# Allow a specific role to access a limited set of URI but let the remaining roles to access to all URI

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, rbac

I'm facing a problem in authorizing a user with role **ROLE_CUSTOMER** to access just to these set of URI as listed below:

```
POST /api/v1/beneficiaries/check 
GET /api/v1/accounts/{accountId}/beneficiary-accounts  
GET /api/v1/accounts/{idAccount} 
GET /api/v1/cards/{cardId}
PUT /api/v1/cards/{cardId}/deactivate
```

but not for the remaining URI

and allow the other users with roles (ROLE_API, ROLE_USER) to access all URI, they should be just authenticated.

How I can achieve that just with antMatchers config.

I have tried for several times with the below config:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/api-docs**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/auth").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/auth-dejamobile").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/hc").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/dictionaries/**").permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/beneficiaries/check").hasRole("CUSTOMER")
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/accounts/*/beneficiary-accounts").hasRole("CUSTOMER")
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/accounts/*").hasRole("CUSTOMER")
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/cards/*").hasRole("CUSTOMER")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT,"/api/v1/cards/*/deactivate").hasRole("CUSTOMER")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").not().hasRole("CUSTOMER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated();


        http
        .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

but the **ROLE_API** and **ROLE_USER** haven't access to the five URI as described above, and **ROLE_CUSTOMER** hasn't access to ***PUT /api/v1/cards/{cardId}/deactivate*** !!

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: 1. Ordering matters. The order in which rules are declared is also the rule in which they are consulted. So `.antMatchers("/api/v1/cards/*").hasRole("CUSTOMER")` also applies to the PUT one already. 2. You are only allowing `ROLE_CUSTOMER`, you want to write your own expression with the `access()` method, something like `access("hasRole('CUSTOMER') or isAuthenticated()"`;

Comment: @M.Deinum Could you give me your new code snippet in the answer please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing Spring Security matching rules the order of the rules matter as the order in which they are defined is also the order in which they are consulted!. So `.antMatchers("/api/v1/cards/*").hasRole("CUSTOMER")` also applies to the PUT one (below this one) already.

Next it your security rule is "allow access to all authenticated users or hasRole Customer" then write that rule. Use something like `access("hasRole('CUSTOMER') or isAuthenticated())`. Although this rule is a bit weird as only `isAuthenticated` would do the trick as well in this specific case.